# Установка AdminLte на Yii2 advanced

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Установил расширение *https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/*.

Но когда в *backend/config/main.php* в `request` прописываю `baseUrl = ''`, то все стили пропадают.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось просто, вместо `baseUrl=''` нужно было указать в кавычках `admin`.